# Oracle : Generate 30 minute interval data for the whole year

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

We have a set of data for the whole year (2013) for a set of StoreIDs. Example for storeId = 1 for the January month below.

```
storeID month   day hh  value

1       jan     wor  1     10
1       jan     wor 2,3,4..12
1       jan     wor  48    50
1       jan     non  1     20
1       jan     non  to    20
1       jan     non  48    20
1       jan     sat  1     30
1       jan     sat  to    31
1       jan     sat  48    35
```

where day= wor(for working days), non (for sunday and public holidays), sat(for saturday)
and hh = (1,2,3...48) representing each half hour interval.

Desired Output:

```
storeID                     date                               value
1   (All Working Dates ex. 1,2,3,6,7,8)/01/2013  12:00:00 AM    10
1   (All Working Dates)/01/2013  12:30:00 AM and so on          12
1   (All Working Dates)/01/2013  11:30:00 PM                    50
1   (non working dates like 5)/01/2013  12:00:00 AM             20
1   (non working dates like 5)/01/2013  12:30:00 AM and so on   21
1   (non working dates like 5)/01/2013  11:30:00 PM             22
1   (Saturday dates ex. 4)/01/2013  12:00:00 AM                 30
1   (Saturday dates ex. 4)/01/2013  12:30:00 AM and so on       31
1   (Saturday dates ex. 4)/01/2013  11:30:00 PM                 35
```

We would need to insert the output in a new table for each storeID for the whole year.
Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11324257/266304) might give you some idea; that's for a single day so you'd need to adapt it for the number of days in the year.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Using the link, I've created a table with 30 minutes interval for the year. Working on the date decode stuff to join with the source data at the moment. Will let you know how it goes.